# How to print documents with latest timestamp in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an ES index where documents are stored via a script. When script runs, All documents stored via this script have same timestamp. So for example if i run this script once each day over three days - there will be three sets of docs with same timestamp.

Now i would like to list only the docs which have latest timestamp.

How can i do this in Kibana?